# C++ scaling all application

Tags: c++, scale, c++builder

I have an application that I need to scale for using by people with vision problems. The program has dynamically appeared components, so when I try to use ScaleBy function or chnge DPI it looks like broken.
Is it possible to make something like to get a capture of the whole app and resize it for user representation?

Comment: Try to use c++ Qt instead of c++ builder.

Comment: The VCL will automatically resize forms based on the DPI of the screen, however this is limited to what you designed in the designer. It won't correct any positions and or sizes you set from code. You have to correct those for current DPI setting yourself.

Comment: I won't check and rewrite all parts of the application that would have wrong look after resize. Instead of it I try to keep original behavior of the program but represent it showing to user in a scaled view.